# Can't get focus to work in FF

Tags: javascript, dom, timeout, focus, dom-manipulation

It works fine in IE but does nothing in FF.

Here's the code I'm using it with.
The code does a some things for proboards.com.
I think the explanation of the code is irrelevant in this case. If not, let me know.

But the focus part is simply to put focus on a single  element.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
var TitleBarGuestMessage="Hello Guest!";
var TitleBarMemberMessage="Welcome Back "+pb_displayname+"!";
var i,table,LTPI,LTPItable,titlerow,titlerowcell1,LTPIrow,LTPIrowcell1,shortcutA,shortcutB,shortcutC,
td=document.getElementsByTagName("td");LTPItable= document.getElementById("rectangle_table");LTPI=document.getElementById("rectangle_right_side");LTPItable.style.width="100%";
shortcutA=LTPI.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
shortcutB=shortcutA.previousSibling.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;shortcutC=shortcutA.firstChild;
shortcutA.previousSibling.parentNode.parentNode.cellSpacing="0";
shortcutA.previousSibling.style.display="none";
shortcutB.className="";
shortcutB.bgColor="transparent";
shortcutC.align="center";
shortcutC.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
shortcutC.className="";
LTPI.style.display="none";
for(i=0;i<td.length;i++){
if(td[i].className=="titlebg" && td[i].colSpan=="2"){
td[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id="forum";}}
table=document.getElementById("forum");
if(pb_action=="home"){
setTimeout(function(){table.focus();}, 2000)};
titlerow=table.insertRow(0);
titlerowcell1=titlerow.insertCell(0);
titlerowcell1.className="titlebg";
titlerowcell1.colSpan="5";
titlerowcell1.id="LTPI_titlebar";
LTPIrow=table.insertRow(1);
LTPIrowcell1=LTPIrow.insertCell(0);
LTPIrowcell1.colSpan="5";
LTPIrowcell1.innerHTML=LTPI.innerHTML;
LTPIrowcell1.id="LTPI_row";
if(pb_username=="Guest"){
titlerowcell1.innerHTML=TitleBarGuestMessage}
else{titlerowcell1.innerHTML=TitleBarMemberMessage}
</script>
```

This is the focus part of the script:

```
if(pb_action=="home"){
    setTimeout(function(){table.focus();}, 2000)};
```

I have also tried:

```
setTimeout("table.focus();",2000);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it is relevant to provide working example, where your error could be seen. Now script does not work cause `pb_displayname` var is not defined

Comment: Please tell me your real code has indentation.

Comment: Is the code executed at the end of the HTML? Because if it is in header or before element with id `#forum` it will never be executed.

Comment: What makes you think that the `#forum` element would be focusable?

Comment: To caligula, [url=http://coderush.boards.net/index.cgi]here[/url] is a live example. You can see it work in IE. The element with the most recent topics in it will have focus 2 seconds after page load. Also I have defined the pb_displayname var and it still don't work.

Comment: @Shawn GameForreal, do you need a scroll to that table? Table can't have a focus, afaik. Your link does not work

Comment: Why would you want focus on a table?  What does focusing a table mean to you? AFAIK, a table is non-interactable, so what's the difference between an focused one, and a non-focused one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because DOM table element does not have `focus` method (although it is implemented in IE). I assume that you need to scroll to that element, so you can do it this way:

```
window.scrollTo(0,table.scrollHeight);
```

Or as in your exact code:

```
if(pb_action=="home"){
    setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,table.scrollHeight)}, 2000)};
```

Comment: @PeeHaa No I haven't gotten that far yet

Comment: @MMahia Yes the code is in the footer under the forum element

Comment: @ Caligula I tried that and it didn't work. I put it in exactly as you have the second example.

Comment: @Shawn GameForreal, consider provide a working link to your page

Comment: @caligua Sorry buddy, http://coderush.boards.net/index.cgi You will not be logged in so the log in box will now be focused in IE. But still not work in FF

Comment: @caligua, That did the job! Thank You very much! So are you saying that FF does not support focus on the table element when you said "this is because DOM table element does not have focus method (although it is implemented in IE)."?